# Android phonegap app scaling too large

Tags: android, cordova

I designed my Android phone gap app to be the dimensions of width: 480px height: 320px and the app has a zoom set on it to scale up fit the screen size of a 7 inch tablet which has the resolution of `1280 x 1024`.

I've tried multiple ways to use zoom: 110% or so to get the app to scale to fit the screen, but when I run the app inside the actual environment it appears much larger than the screen.  Did I miss something do I need meta code to emulate my scaling better the way it works inside a web browser?

Inside my head I have

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "initial-scale = 1.0">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=480,height=320">
```

Any help provided would be great.

Comment: how your <head></head>looks like ? maybe <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"> this would help

Comment: I added my head code above.

Comment: Now that I think about it maybe the problem is the width,height being defined?

Comment: try to change it to device -> width,height

Comment: what does the "initial-scale = 1.0" do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should read this [article](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)
Basically you should consider screen density not the actual width or height of device and than try to compensate with zoom.Check the section "Building web pages to support different screen densities"